# how to get attached file preview of a Custom object record in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning

I created records in a custom object. For each record I uploaded a file(which will store as a salesforce file) through a lightning component. If i click on record name, It will show the attached file preview of that record. I am able to show file preview temporarily using Lightning Openfiles event. But it will lost if I refresh the screen. Can anyone please suggest me the solution ?

Comment: Please can you provide your code?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the problem is for which you are seeking a solution. In addition to a code sample, as Robs asked, I would suggest you describe your problem in more detail and/or provide screen shots of the behavior you are trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular `img` tag.

```
<img src="mysite.force.com/mycommunity/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download" + {!v.documentId} />
```

Just be sure to query and store the `documentId` in an `aura:attribute' or as a field on the object you already queried.